# Не могу завести вебсокеты ratchet на vps + nginx + yii2, постоянно ошибка: WebSocket opening handshake timed out

Tags: php, nginx, websocket, vps, ratchet

WebSocket connection to 'wss://"domen":5555/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out

Сервер на linux.

Пытался настроить вставив настройки прокси для основного домена, так же пытался сделать поддомен, все безуспешно. Так же поставил cerbot для сертификатов.

Конфиг nginx:

```
server {
    server_name domen.ru www.domen.ru;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    root /var/www/domen.ru/frontend/web/;
    #root /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
    index index.php;
    access_log /var/www/domen.ru/logs/frontend-access.log;
    error_log /var/www/domen.ru/logs/frontend-error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ ^/assets/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~* /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domen.ru-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domen.ru-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location /websocket {
        # switch off logging
        access_log off;

        # redirect all HTTP traffic to localhost
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5555;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # WebSocket support (nginx 1.4)
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        # Path rewriting
        rewrite /websocket/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # timeout extension, possibly keep this short if using a ping strategy
        proxy_read_timeout 99999s;
    }
}
```

На сколько я понимаю лучше сделать отдельный конфиг файл, возможно с поддоменом, вопрос только как сделать так, чтобы certbot выдал сертификат для wss, при попытках он ругается: Domain: wss.domain.ru
Type:   dns
Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for wss.domain.ru - check
that a DNS record exists for this domain

Как лучше все таки завести работу сокетов (в иделае подробный гайд)) )?

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось на много проще чем я думал, надо было все перезапустить, выдать сертификаты и подключаться по wss://domen.ru/websocket